# Using a RequireJS module more than once does not run

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Running `require(['pages/home'])` will work once but if I use `require(['pages/home'])` again then it won't run.
The module "pages/home" is a file named "home.js" in a directory named "pages".

**main.js**

```
require(['pages/home']);
```

**pages/home.js**

```
define('pages/home', function() {
    console.log('running pages/home module');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RequireJS modules are singletons. It loads a module once and only once. If a module has been loaded already, what you get if you load it again is a reference to the same module as originally loaded. The factory function you pass to `define` won't be run a second time.

So what you are seeing is exactly what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Static code in modules isn't supposed to be evaluated more than once, just like a script loaded through a normal `<script>` tag won't be run more than once during the page load.

Imagine if a module contained code like:

```
define('my-module', function () {
  var foo = foo || 0;
  var bar = ++foo;
});
```

You should expect `bar` and `foo` to both `=== 1`, but if the module was run repeatedly and a global `foo` existed, that may not be the case. Admittedly, this is a very contrived example, but evaluating a module repeatedly could cause serious problems.

Answer (score 0):

Make it return a function/object that can be executed after you require it.

```
define('pages/home', function() {
    return function(){
       console.log('running pages/home module');
    };
});
require(['pages/home'], function(resultFunc){
   window.YourFunc = resultFunc;
});
```

Now you can execute your function whenever you want

Comment: The entire point of AMD or any other moduling system is to *prevent* the need for using global variables. -1.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I know it is a bad practice to use global variables. I am just giving an example of what the result of the factory function of requirejs would look like. I would expect that he/she would store the outcome in some kind of namespace that he/she uses inside his/her application.

Comment: You can't really "expect" anything from the asker.